# List not populating with a JsonP proxy

Tags: javascript, list, proxy, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I want to have a Navigation view. I am trying to populate the list in Sencha Touch using a JsonP proxy.

Here's the sample code snippet of what I have tried till now :

```
var view = Ext.define('MyApp.view.NavigateView', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype:'navigateview',

    config : {
        fullscreen:true,
        styleHtmlContent:true,
        scrollable:true,

        items : [
            {
                title:'Navigation',
                items : [
                    {
                        xtype:'list',
                        store: {
                            fields : ['title','author'],
                            proxy : {
                                type:'jsonp',
                                url:'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://feeds.feedburner.com/SenchaBlog',
                                    reader: {
                                         type: 'json',
                                         rootProperty: 'responseData.feed.entries'
                                    }
                            },
                            autoLoad:true,
                        },
                        itemTpl:'<div class="contact">{title} <strong>{author}</strong></div>',
                        listeners : {
                            itemtap : function(){
                                Ext.Msg.alert('Called');
                                }
                            }
                        }
                ],

            }
        ]   
   }
});
```

But the problem is, my list is not getting populated. No items are being shown up in the list.

Also, I am constantly getting this error on console.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://api.tinyhippos.com/xhr_proxy?tinyhippos_apikey=ABC&tinyhippos_rurl=list.php%3F_dc%3D1334462633038%26page%3D1%26start%3D0%26limit%3D25.
>   Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Anyone please guide ? Anything that I am missing here ?

Comment: looks like your error is not in using googleapis feeds where jsonp is used.
Where are you using tinyhippos.com, that should be your error location.

Comment: Nope, i don't think so. When I provided the 'sencha-touch.css' file used for sencha touch charts instead of that used for normal sencha touch applications, I was able to see the data, but wasn't rendered properly. So, data is coming but not getting rendered properly. What could be the reason ?

Comment: but if you look at the error, it says XMLHttpRequest cannot load something from tinyhippos,

Answer (score 2):

i was facing the same error when using AJAX request in cross domain.
have a look [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP)

you have to make sure that the server part is configured properly using jsonp

as a first step identify if your application will run correctly when you disable web security in your browser

locate your chrome installation directory
then type in your cmd:  `chrome --disable-web-security`

Answer (score 0):

Your [Ext.navigation.View](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View) object is containing one [Ext.Component](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Component) object (xtype not defined so defaulted to 'component') that is containing your list.  If you put your list directly as an item of your view, it'll be rendered:

```
var view = Ext.define('MyApp.view.NavigateView', {
  extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
  xtype: 'navigateview',

  config : {
    fullscreen: true,
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    scrollable: true,

    items : [{
      title: 'Navigation',
      xtype: 'list',
      store: {
        fields: ['title','author'],
        proxy: {
          type: 'jsonp',
          url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://feeds.feedburner.com/SenchaBlog',
          reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'responseData.feed.entries'
          }
        },
        autoLoad:true
      },
      itemTpl: '<div class="contact">{title} <strong>{author}</strong></div>'
    }]
  }
});
```

Note1: Not sure why your code is not working.

Note2: The error your mentioned is not related to your code snippet